# Sound start buzzing/stuttering/lagging after a while when two users are logged in (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, graphics-card, motherboard

stackoverflow.

I have an issue with the sound first, but overall whole system. I have two users on my machine - main user (admin) with games and my personal apps and work account. After I log in to both users after a couple hours sound start buzzing/lagging/stuttering in both accounts and it progressively gets worse. At first games seems unaffected but after a day or so FPS plummets, everything starts lagging. If at first sign of trouble I sign out of work account (haven't tested the other way around actually) - all issues go away.

Additional facts:

- After updating NVIDIA drivers it gets much worse, but after deleting and re-installing audio drivers it gets better.
- When it gets bad, just shutdown is not enough. Need full power off (Motherboard has lights, so it is clear when it fully lost power)
- Also after a while Wi-Fi starts disconnecting too (I didn't want to drill the wall to get ethernet, so I use ASUS PCE-AC51 card)

Motherboard is ASUS PRIME B450-PLUS. Processor Ryzen 5 3600. Video card RTX 2060.

I am very puzzled by this issue and exhausted my knowledge of dealing with it. Is it hardware issue? I tried swapping memory modules and was thinking about swapping video cards (fortunately I have a second PC with pretty similar config), but if there is a simpler way to diagnose or fix this, I would like to avoid it. And it starts with sound, so... if it is hardware - it should be motherboard? Anyway, I welcome your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not hardware. I am unfortunately, still not sure what exactly is, but it looks like, because WSL2 is enabled on both my accounts so virtualization is trying to work on both and some hiccup happens. If I only work in one of my accounts at the time (signing out from second one) - no issues.